What's the right use of the idiom "die Zügel in der Hand halten"?
I wanna know if the use of this Idiomatische Redewendung "die Zügel in der Hand halten" is suitable in this phrase?

Zusätzlich dazu darf man nicht außer Acht lassen, dass Sportaktivitäten zu einem verbesserten körperlichen Zustand führen, um die Gesundheit die Zügel in der Hand zu halten."

The goal is to express something similar to : "um die Gesundheit zu kontrollieren".

The English equivalent is "to be in the driver's seat". The meaning is "to be in control". BTW, your German sentence is grammatically wrong. The infinitive group ("zu halten") has two accusatives (Gesundheite and Zügel).

There are some reasons why the phrase does not fit well into your example sentence, mostly deriving from grammar:

We have two presumed accusatives, die Zügel und die Gesundheit which float beneath each other with unclear relation.
The last auxiliary phrase starts with um but seems more provide a  continuation than an additional target to achieve.

The first issue could be fixed with um die Zügel bezüglich der Gesundheit in der Hand zu halten. But the sentence would be simpler and easier to understand as:

Zusätzlich dazu darf man nicht außer Acht lassen, dass Sportaktivitäten zu einem verbesserten körperlichen Zustand führen und so die Gesundheit fördern.

A good example can be found in corpora section of DWDS, from Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung, 02.10.2023:

[Die Regierung] wird angeführt von [], der nach der []-Affäre Ministerpräsident wurde, wobei aber sein Mentor [] als Parteichef weiter die Zügel in der Hand hielt.


Die Phrase kann verwendet, muss aber anders eingebettet werden.

Zusätzlich dazu darf man nicht außer Acht lassen, dass Sportaktivitäten zu einem verbesserten körperlichen Zustand führen,  ...


um der Gesundheit Zügel in der Hand zu halten.
um die Zügel der Gesundheit in der Hand zu halten.

Von der Semantik würde auch

um die Gesundheitszügel in der Hand zu halten.

funktionieren, aber ein Wort aus dem stehenden Ausdruck in eine Hauptwortverkettung zu verschieben schwächt die Wiedererkennung der Redewendung.

Still not a great idiom for this and not a great sentence semantically. On an unrelated note, the question is in English.
